# Javascript/Jquery get num row from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, count

I have a textarea. I would count lines of my input.

My simple countLines function works with all other regex, but not in this case.

```
function countLines(str){
  return (str.split("\r\n|\r|\n").length -1);
}

alert( countLines($("#myTextArea").html() );
```

Why its return is 0 even if I have multiple lines of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probally want the regex form.

```
function countLines(str){
   return (str.split(/\r?\n|\r/).length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in a string to `.split()` instead of a regex.  Use slashes (not quotes) to delimit your regex: `/\r\n|\r|\n/`.

```
function countLines(str){  
  return (str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length -1);  
}
```

But, subtracting 1 from the length will only be correct if your textarea is empty.  In the case that your textarea contains:

```
line 1
line 2
```

There will only be one `\n`.  Calling `.split()` will return a two-item array and `countLines()` will return `1` when there are actually two lines, right?

Comment: Note that `.html()` will not return user input, for that you have to use `.val()`. Here is a simple demo to show the difference between using `.html()` and `.val()` on a textarea: http://jsfiddle.net/YZVP6/

Answer (score 2):

Don't use split. Here's an even better way since you'll probably be working with a DOM element. The example below counts the lines of code in a "pre" element. Substitute "pre" for any selector desired. Enjoy.

```js
var count = $('pre').text().match(/\r?\n|\r/mg).length;
```